# python packages in ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I was trying to install the django framework with pip.

```
sudo pip install django
```

And it was installed successfully but the django wasn't running as expected so I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

with this django was installed but it was the older version=**1.7.6** instead of **1.10.4**

After that I came to know that using the pip the django was installed in this location

> ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

And there are few other packages as well in that directory.

Why are these packages in **~/.local/lib** ?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Packages are installed in this directory when one uses `pip install --user`. You could perhaps try `pip uninstall --user django`. Hm, I read that --user won't work and that you simply need  to `pip uninstall`

Comment: Try virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: I want to install django globally on my machine. Will it help @Chikiro

Comment: No, but it helps if you need different python package versions on one machine.

Comment: Install with sudo/as root.